# convert gremlin queries to cypher query

Tags: neo4j

our system is using a graph database( not neo4j )and it's in live .
Wanted to migrate it to Neo4j.

we have used gremlin for graph traversal and approximately 10000 gremlin traversal queries(read intensive system) and impossible to translate each and every query to cypher .
It will lead to a very big change in the system , testing etc .

Hence we are looking for a gremlin to cypher translator which is something similar to open cypher library which converts cypher to gremlin.
Input is cypher query string and output is gremlin.

Similarly if we have any such library for taking gremlin query string as input and converting it to cypher query string so that we can seamlessly migrate our system.

We have tried a gremlin bolt driver [it relied on a lot of roundtrips.] but it didn't work as expected and it is not taking gremlin query as string and also big queries are not working .

Comment: Rather than converting all your Gremlin queries to Cypher, have you considered using neo4j-gremlin? You can execute existing Gremlin queries against a Neo4j database; most queries (if not all) should work out of the box unless you've been using some provider-specific features. See https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.5.2/reference/#neo4j-gremlin

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have already been discussing this already with Michael Hunger, who happens to be one of the most knowledgeable people when it comes to this kind of things.  I don't think that there is anything better than the bolt driver at this moment.

The number of 10000 query statements makes me wonder whether there isn't a pattern in the structure of these statements? In our own platform, we have a mechanism to write part of the queries (Cypher, Gremlin, Sparql) dynamically. It might be an approach that could work for your case as well.

Comment: Gremlin traversal queries of 15 diff modules in the system 
not sure about the pattern which your asking and how it would help to transalate it from Gremlin ti cypher ?

Comment: I’m not talking graph patterns, but patterns in the statements. Anyway, more info would be needed to say something concrete.